# Using serialisable object from internal storage leads to memory leak? how to avoid

Tags: android

I searched a solution but I didn't find it. I write an ArrayList containing my Name object to a file, and the retrieved ArrayList will later be used by different activities for the same purpose. This object is a separate class in a separate package.
I write the ArrayList with ObjectOutputStream and  then close the FileOutpoutStream and ObjectOutputStream. I do it many times in an activity 's lifetime.

The object is like:

```
public class Name implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
String name;
int id;

public Name (String name, int id){

    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

    public String getId(){
    return this.id;
}
```

When I want to retrieve it, I create a new ArrayList of Name object and use ObjectInputStream to add elements by doing

```
ArrayList<Name> array = new ArrayList<Name>();
array.addAll((ArrayList<Name>)ois.readObject());
```

I avoided doing

```
array = (ArrayList<Name>) ois.readObject();
```

I thought there will be no reference this way.

I then close the FileInputStream and ObjectInputStream. I do this many times in an activity's lifecycle as well.

When I check MAT with eclipse, the histogram shows that memory contains many Name objects and thus, block the activities to destroy themself.

I tried to reset() Streams before closing them, I tried the opposite too, tried to only reset() whithout closing, I tried the same onDestroy(), but every actions lead to Exceptions and unwanted behaviors.

Changing the serial doesn't work to, it doesn't write or gives Exceptions so it seems that the serial must remain static and must not be removed.

How should I deal whith this, considering that this ArrayList must be stocked on the storage and shared with different activities? Should I use SharedPreferences instead or something else?

Comment: Does this problem actually affect the foreground activity, or only the ones on the backstack?

Comment: It affects all the activities using this object, other activities don't remain on memory. the memory keeps highing up and then OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: according to my research, it is a known problem. ObjectOutputStream keeps previous elements alive. The solution seemed to be reset(); but it doesn't work, it gets even worse

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I originally wanted to suggest moving the serialization code into an application-local Service, since one reason for the large number of instances is that you create **copies** for each activity during deserialization. But if it's an OOME, it looks to me the core problem is with a leak somewhere within your foreground activity. I'm not really that familiar with the ObjectXStreams to suggest a solution in this case, for these scenarios I usually use OrmLite or something similar.

Comment: If I were pressed for time and in your place, I'd simply use an SQLite DB (since it's really only two fields), but that's a workaround, and really doesn't solve your underlying problem.

Comment: It will make me change all the code and bring a lot of bugs to fix. the Name objet is a simple example, the object I use is more complex.